# Python alternative for PHP feof

Tags: python, php

PHP code:

```
...
fseek($filesrc, 40);
while ( !feof($filesrc) ) {
    $slen_1 = fread($filesrc, 4);
...
```

`$slen_1` for example prints "**Stop route**"

Python code:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as filesrc:
    filesrc.seek(40)
    while True:
        b = filesrc.read(1)
        if not b:
            break

        slen_1 = filesrc.read(4)
```

But. This python code prints "**Sop rote**". And I know why. Because of this line `b = filesrc.read(1)`. Any ides how can I check for end of file in python of binary file? Thanks in advance.

Is the best way is `i = 0`... `i = i+1 while filesrc.read(1)` and then read again and do loop to known `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as filesrc:
    filesrc.seek(40)
    while True:
        slen_1 = filesrc.read(4)
        if not slen_1:
            break
```